# Is the new CiviCRM menu bar broken when using the Edge browser?

Tags: menu

I was providing a bit of support to a user yesterday who was struggling with how to do something in Civi (5.13.1). When they shared their screen with it became immediately apparent why. They were using Edge as their browser, and the menu bar in Civi simply wasn't appearing for them. We could not see anything obvious in their browser console that might have caused this.
They are working round the issue using Firefox.

Comment: I don't see this on the public demo using edge? Is there maybe something else about that install? Also which CMS? There was an issue with colors for the new menu bar which is now fixed, but maybe it affected edge differently. If it's color-related, there are now some settings at /civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1

Comment: Thanks. All I could see was that the Civi menu bar wasn't there, the Drupal admin menu was displayed when it should not have been. And as I don't have a Windows machine I can't look into it in any more detail. The site is pretty straight-ahead installation, no fancy customisations.